# WPF Binding vs. Manual Update in Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

So, I've got a UserControl which displays basic information about a customer extracted from a file object.

The control looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ns.Gui.pnlDebtor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="230" d:DesignWidth="460" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Ns.Gui">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Debtor" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="56" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="28" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="380*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Name:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Address:" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Customer Nr.:" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblCustomerNr" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="tbName" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="False" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:pnlDebtor, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DebtorName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="tbAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:pnlDebtor, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Adresse, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="tbCustomerNr" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <Button Content="Debtor Details" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="btnDetails" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Name and Address Textboxes are bound to DebtorName and DebtorAddress properties of the pnlDebtor UserControl.

Codebehind is like so:

```
public partial class pnlDebtor : UserControl
{
    private MyFile file = null;
    public MyFile File
    {
        get
        {
            return file;
        }

        set
        {
            file = value;
            tbCustomerNr.Text = file.CustomerNo;
        }
    }

    private Contact debtor = null;
    public Contact Debtor
    {
        get
        {
            if (debtor == null)
            {
                if (File != null)
                {
                    debtor = AbstractDataObject.GetObject4ID<Contact>(File.DebtorID);
                }
            }

            return debtor;
        }
    }

    private Address debtorAddress = null;
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (debtorAddress == null)
            {
                if (Debtor != null)
                {
                    List<Address> lsAddresses = AbstractDataObject.GetObject4NonIdProperty<Address>("ContactID", Debtor.ID);

                    if (lsAddresses.Any())
                    {
                        debtorAddress = lsAddresses[0];

                        result += lsAddresses[0].Street + "\r\n"
                            + lsAddresses[0].PostalCode + " " + lsAddresses[0].City;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result += debtorAddress.Street + "\r\n"
                    + debtorAddress.PostalCode + " " + debtorAddress.City;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    private string strDebtorName = string.Empty;
    public string DebtorName
    {
        get
        {
            if (strDebtorName== string.Empty)
            {
                if (Debtor != null)
                {
                    strDebtorName = Debtor.Name1;

                    if (Debtor.FirstName != null)
                        strSchuldnerName += ", " + Debtor.FirstName;
                }
            }

            return strDebtorName;
        }
    }

    public pnlDebtor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As you can see, unlike the Name and Address Textboxes, my CustomerNr Textbox is populated in the codebehind. When I pass in my file object, I extract the customer number and assign that value to the Text property of the appropriate Textbox. Both methods work, but the first method (Binding) seems to be prefered for WPF. Why?

To me, the disadvantages are:
1) Logic and presentation aren't separated. If I send my xaml to someone in design, there's a chance they could screw up my binding.
2) If I'm debugging and set a breakpoint, the Text property of my bound Textboxes is always an empty string. I can't see what's going on.

So, what are the advantages of using binding? Why is it the preferred method? Use small words. This is my first WPF project. :)

Comment: Like you said, this is to separate presentation and logic and to keep application loosely coupled. For the person designing the XAML, he should be careful with data binding aspects or you could add that to XAML yourself.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't put all that logic in the `get`, that logic should be executed when the UserControl is loaded. You should separate presentation and logic even more by [implementing MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the missing link here is MVVM. Your bindings to properties in codebehind mean that that particular UserControl is still tightly coupled to that particular class. I wouldn't have said that it's any better than the version without bindings. The codebehind class won't compile unless the XAML page is bundled with it, because there's a reference to `tbCustomerNr.Text`.

Using MVVM and bindings, the ViewModel is *completely* isolated from the View. I can, if I like, delete the Views entirely from my program and the ViewModels will still compile without any complaints. This means that the ViewModel logic can be reused easily, and logic and UI development tasks can be separated cleanly.